# Concerting char* to string to be read into file?

Tags: c++, string, char, cin

I am trying to read in an input from a user and I know my method needs a char* but is there anyway to make the input of cin able to be used by that char? (look at the comment at char* x.)

```
string y;
cout << "Enter your file: ";
cin >> y;

char * x = //here is where the string needs to go. If I type in the actual address it works, but I need it to work when the user just cin's the address//

string line,character_line;
ifstream myfile;
myfile.open (x);
while(getline(myfile,line))
{
    if (line[0] != '0' && line[0] != '1')
    {
        character_line = line;
    }

}
```

Comment: Use std::string::c_str() to convert to a c-style string

Answer (score 1):

```
char * x = y.c_str();
```

A simple Google would have provided the result :)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the `c_str()` method of the std::string class.  This works:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(void) {
  std::string y;
  std::cout << "Enter your file: ";
  std::cin >> y;
  std::string line,character_line;
  std::ifstream myfile;
  myfile.open (y.c_str(), std::ifstream::in);
  while(getline(myfile,line))
  {
    if (line[0] != '0' && line[0] != '1')
    {   
      character_line = line;
    }   

  }
  return 0;
}
```